# I executed a transaction but it does not appear in history

Tags: bug

I found a bug when calling the API.

The transaction with nonce **#42** is succesfully executed as you can see in the explorer (*https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x77cf43c72af8042c447dbb630bfa821a67919161a72d078f46ee85a823351201*) but the UI does not show it in history. When I try to get the transactions via API I can see `isExecuted = false` and `isSuccessful = true`, so I assume there is some bug in the process and **isExecuted** should have been marked as **true**. This leads to your UI not showing the transaction anywhere. Check UI here: https://app.safe.global/transactions/history?safe=matic%3A0xeD2b8B7D2f768FDbedFBb6c5f4dd375Aa88EB5D6

Thanks for your help

Comment: This isnt Safe's tech support, good sir

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a third party tool.